# SyntaxError: invalid syntax with Chicken coop door script

Tags: python, syntax-error, sh

I am new to python, I have been trying to get a piece of code working to control a chicken coop door.
The github link is https://github.com/ryanrdetzel/CoopControl

The problem I have is that if I run server.py it does not get the MAILGUN_KEY variable from the coop.conf file. So I tried running start.sh I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax error, but I can not see for the life of me what can be wrong.

This is the start.sh file

`sudo MAILGUN_KEY = 'key-c5e6aa4561a7077e8c0fc55e594cf26' MAILGUN_URL = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxc1ea9c71ab95485dac75b03cc5dd5883.mailgun.org/messages' MAILGUN_RECIPIENT = 'google@google.org' python server.py`

The Syntax error is under the `Y` of `MAILGUN_KEY`, I am running python verson 3. I don't know if that would make a difference.

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: You have spaces around the `=`?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up shell script syntax and Python syntax. Your problem is not at all related to Python.

To set environment variables for single invocation of binary, correct form is:

```sh
ENV1=VAL1 ENV2=VAL2 /path/to/bin some args
```

So in your case it would be:

```sh
MAILGUN_KEY=key-c5e6aa4561a7077e8c0fc55e594cf26 MAILGUN_URL=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxc1ea9c71ab95485dac75b03cc5dd5883.mailgun.org/messages MAILGUN_RECIPIENT=google@google.org sudo python server.py
```

Comment: I have changed start.sh but now I get an error on the L of MAILGUN_URL, should the variables be separated?